# What is the probability of a circle sector being chosen at random?

Tags: probability, geometry, circles

[image: Circle and it's sectors]

What should I do in order to find the probability of the sector? Can you please give me the answer to this. It will really help me out if you do.

Comment: I have been on these question for the last two days. And i was out of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(Desirable\ event)=\frac{Measure\ of\ Desirable\ Outcomes}{Measure\ of\ Total\ Outcomes}$$

This measure could be of any type, area, time period, sets, etc. In this case it is degrees.

The total outcomes all come within $360^\circ$. So,

$$P(Point\ lies\ in\ given\ angle)=\frac{63^\circ}{360^\circ}=\frac7{40}$$